# Application gateway rewrite rule, remove / at the end of url

Tags: url-rewriting, azure-application-gateway

i have an application gateway v2 standard with private ip and i have this use case:

- on imperva we have this url myapp.mydomain.com with a redirect to [www.mydomain.com/something/](http://www.mydomain.com/something/), this url is on an application gateway but i see that app gw put at the end the / . I would like to remove it to have [www.mydomain.com/something](http://www.mydomain.com/something), there is a way to remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the same URL  like below:***

[image]

Application gateway is used to make URL redirects, however one of the routing rules, which takes users to an external website, adds a trailing slash "/" at the end of the URL and causes problems to resolve this issue try the below step:

In your backend target try to disable the include path as ***NO*** like below:

[image]

***When I try to pass the URL I got the result successfully like below:***

[image]

Comment: hi thanks, i configured this on my path based rule but i'm getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS i do not understand what is the problem